Mock or stub a QEvent?
Is there a way to mock a QEvent and pass it as a parameter?
I have a test like this which I want to include:
def test_table_resize_event_sets_column_widths():
    table = results_table_classes.ResultsTableView(None)

    with mock.patch.object(table, 'setColumnWidth') as mock_set:
        mock_event = mock.Mock()
        mock_size = mock.Mock()
        mock_event.size = mock.Mock(return_value=mock_size)
        mock_size.width = mock.Mock(return_value=300)
        table.resizeEvent(mock_event)

    
    assert mock_set.call_args_list[0].args == (0, int(300 * 0.20))
    assert mock_set.call_args_list[1].args == (1, int(300 * 0.80))

This test should lead to an implementation something like this:
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    width = event.size().width()
    self.setColumnWidth(0, int(width * 0.20)) # 20% Width Column
    self.setColumnWidth(1, int(width * 0.80)) # 80% Width Column       

But I get

E           TypeError: resizeEvent(self, e: QResizeEvent): argument 1
has unexpected type 'Mock'

I tried creating mock_event like so:
mock_event = mock.MagicMock(spec=QtGui.QResizeEvent)

... but I still get the same error. Maybe PyQt has some extra level of type-checking with this kind of method?
If it helps at all, I have installed pytest_qt, so the qtbot fixture is available, if this can somehow be used to solve this.

The error you report doesn't seem to come from the resizeEvent() override you showed (see the argument difference between event and e). This means that you either are overriding that function somewhere else, or the provided code is not the actual code. Please provide a proper [mre].
